# Creating scheduled task with c# (Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper)

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I'm trying to create a task using the Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper. However, it is failing.

If I do it using a local user, without admin privileges, it fails with access denied. Conversely, if I try and run it with an elevated user, the code completes without error, but I then can't see the task in the task scheduler.

Code is just lifted directly from the documentation: http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/documentation

and is:

```
      using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
      {
         // Create a new task definition and assign properties
         TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
         td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";

         // Add a trigger that, starting tomorrow, will fire every other week on Monday
         // and Saturday and repeat every 10 minutes for the following 11 hours
         WeeklyTrigger wt = new WeeklyTrigger();
         wt.StartBoundary = DateTime.Today.AddDays(1);
         wt.DaysOfWeek = DaysOfTheWeek.Monday | DaysOfTheWeek.Saturday;
         wt.WeeksInterval = 2;
         wt.Repetition.Duration = TimeSpan.FromHours(11);
         wt.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
         td.Triggers.Add(wt);

         // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
         td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("notepad.exe", "c:\\test.log", null));

         // Register the task in the root folder
         ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Test", td);
      }
```

So I don't think it's a code issue - more to do with me not using it right!

Comment: And do you see it if you run `SCHTASKS` from the command prompt (and elevated?)

Answer (score 2):

@rene pointed me in the right direction. Hadn't realised you can't see all users' tasks in scheduled tasks in Windows 8.

If I run as admin (you have to do this through Computer Management - can't run Task Scheduler as admin direct) all the tasks show up.